# Jupyter Notebook Windows 10 Access Denied

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

My IT installed anaconda for me on windows 10 (I don't have admin rights) and when I try to launch jupyter notebook from the anaconda prompt I get an "access denied" error message.

I can launch jupyter notebook from the anaconda navigator and it runs just fine but I would like to launch jupyter notebook from the prompt so that I can set the default directory.

Currently I have not found a way to change the directory once jupyter notebook is up and running and I have to save all my files in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your admin rights installing Anaconda in program files or some other protected folders.  You can install Anaconda in your home directory without bothering the sysadmin.  Have your IT staff uninstall it first (for cleanliness sake) .  Then install Anaconda using your own login and when you are prompted for the admin password don't give it.  It will still continue.  Then Jupyter notebook will launch from the directory it installs into (c:\users\\appdata\something... )